# How to modify apache httpd config files on openshift

Tags: openshift

How can i modify some configuration in openshift , I am serving a jekyll site by directly linking the static built html page , ( as opposed to building it through source , which was proving to be a pain ).

But now even though almost all of my blog works fine , the /about and /contact pages do not work , because those are /about.html and /contact.html , the ruby server rewrites the request and I am trying to do the same in apache. Is there any way to add mod_rewrite module to apache httpd on openshift. I tried the console tool , to see if I can ssh , but it logs in says using project "xyz" and then i go back to terminal. Totally new to openshift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration you're looking for isn't actually part of Openshift; its part of the container running Apache, so even if you open a shell into that container (which you can do using `oc rsh <pod-name>`) any changes you make won't persist past the life of that container.

You'll need to modify the Docker image, and then re-deploy using your modified image. It looks like mod_rewrite might be installed by default , but not enabled, which someone explains how to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49809748/add-mod-rewrite-to-docker-image-httpdalpine). Here's the page with the info about the [httpd image](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd), and there's also some instructions for changing the configuration there.